# Why is an entity enclosed in a content object with Spring Data REST when accessed via an association link?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

Using Spring Data REST with via `JPARepsitory` repositories, I have two entities that have a one-to-many relationship.

```
@Entity
class Owner {

    // owner attributes...

    @OneToMany
    Set<Item> items;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
class Item {

    // item attributes...

    @ManyToOne
    Owner owner;
}
```

The setup is Owner with id 1 has an Item with id 5.

When I call `http://localhost:8080/api/items/5` I get something like

```
{
  // item attributes
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/items/5"
    },
    "item": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/items/5"
    },
    "owner": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/items/5/owner"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, when I call `http://localhost:8080/api/items/5/owner` I get

```
{
  "content": {
    // owner attributes
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/owners/1"
    },
    "owner": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/owners/1"
    },
    "items": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/owners/1/items"
    }
  }
}
```

However, if I call `http://localhost:8080/api/owners/1` (which is the same entity, but at the identity href instead of the association href) I get something like

```
{
  // owner attributes
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/owners/1"
    },
    "owner": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/owners/1"
    },
    "items": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/owners/1/items"
    }
  }
}
```

Here, Owner is wrapped in an extra `content` object when being called from a singular association resource.

**Update to clarify**

I would expect if I were to call the `self` href I would get back the exact same representation, but in this case I don't. I get the canonical entity representation.

My question is, why is this the case? Should an entity returned via an association resource have a `self` href that is the URI the entity was retrieved from or should the entity returned via the association resource have the same representation of that of the entity's item resource?

In short, when I call `http://localhost:8080/api/items/5/owner` I would expect to get

```
{
  "content": {
    // owner attributes
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/items/5/owner"
      // ^^^ the URI that was retrieved that will always return this representation
    },
    "owner": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/owners/1"
      // ^^^ the canonical entity URI
    },
    "items": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/owners/1/items"
    }
  }
}
```

**OR**

```
{
  // owner attributes
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/owners/1"
    },
    "owner": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/owners/1"
    },
    "items": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/owners/1/items"
    }
  }
}
// ^^^ The canonical entity representation (no "content" wrapper)
```

but not a mix of the two.

Comment: Why would you call `http://localhost:8080/api/items/5/owner` instead of the owner's URI?

Comment: Because I'm using the `merchant` link from the Item. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2):

`http://localhost:8080/api/items/5/owner` refers to a so called [association resource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.6.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#repository-resources.association-resource). It doesn't point to the "real" owner resource.

It's purpose is to handle associations. E.g. sending a request with `DELETE` would only remove the owner from the item, but not delete the actual owner entity.

Depending on the configuration you can get all attributes of the owner embedded. That's what you get as `content`.

Comment: I get that it's the association resource. The documentation makes no mention that the representation of the entity from an association resource URL would be different from the representation of an entity from its identity URL. Also, the URLs in `_links` are identical. I can't call the `self` link returned from the association resource response and get the same response.